# "OrderedDict()" Itself printing when using OrderedDict()

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to print an ordered dictionary using OrderedDict, but when I print it, "OrderedDict" also prints. FYI this is just a code segment, not the whole code. What can I do to fix this? I'm using Python 3.2

Looks like this:

```
def returnAllStats(ints):
    choices = ["Yes","No"]
    dictInfo = {"Calories":ints[2], "Servings per Container":ints[0], "Amount per Serving":ints[1], "Total Fat":(ints[3]/100)*ints[2], "Saturated Fat":(ints[4]/100)*(ints[3]/100)*ints[2], "Cholesterol":ints[5], "Fiber":ints[6], "Sugar":ints[7], "Protein":ints[8], "Sodium":ints[9], "USA":choices[ints[10]], "Caffeine":ints[11]}
    dictInfo = collections.OrderedDict(dictInfo)
    return dictInfo
```

And I'm getting this in the text file to which this is writing:

```
('snack', 'bananana')OrderedDict([('USA', 'No'), ('Sodium', 119), ('Calories', 479), ('Servings per Container', 7), ('Sugar', 49), ('Saturated Fat', 37.553599999999996), ('Total Fat', 234.71), ('Cholesterol', 87), ('Amount per Serving', 40), ('Fiber', 1), ('Caffeine', 7), ('Protein', 53)])
```

Thanks!

Comment: You know that in your example the order of the output of `dictInfo` is UNORDERED since you first create a regular dict before you create an `OrderedDict` from that, right?

Answer (score 5):

You have several options.

You can use a list comprehension and print that:

```
>>> od
OrderedDict([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)])
>>> [(k,v) for k,v in od.items()]
[('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)]
```

Or, knowing that the order may change, you can just convert to a dict if you want that output:

```
>>> dict(od)
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}
```

(With Python 3.6, a regular `dict` [does maintain order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-ordered-in-python-3-6). Use Python 3.6 and the order will not change. That is likely going to be the case in the future, but not yet guaranteed.)

Finally, you can subclass `OrderDict` and replace the `__str__` method with a format that you want:

```
class Mydict(OrderedDict):
    def __str__(self):
        return ''.join([str((k, v)) for k,v in self.items()])

>>> md=Mydict([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)])   
>>> md     # repr
Mydict([('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3)])
>>> print(md)
('one', '1')('two', '2')('three', '3')
```

(Change the `__repr__` method if you want the output of the repr to be different...)

---

Final note:

With this:

```
def returnAllStats(ints):
    choices = ["Yes","No"]
    dictInfo = {"Calories":ints[2], "Servings per Container":ints[0], "Amount per Serving":ints[1], "Total Fat":(ints[3]/100)*ints[2], "Saturated Fat":(ints[4]/100)*(ints[3]/100)*ints[2], "Cholesterol":ints[5], "Fiber":ints[6], "Sugar":ints[7], "Protein":ints[8], "Sodium":ints[9], "USA":choices[ints[10]], "Caffeine":ints[11]}
    dictInfo = collections.OrderedDict(dictInfo)
    return dictInfo
```

You are actually getting an UNORDERED dict result since you are creating the OrderedDict from a dict literal which is unordered.

You would want to do instead:

```
def returnAllStats(ints):
    choices = ["Yes","No"]
    return collections.OrderedDict([("Calories",ints[2]), ("Servings per Container",ints[0]), ("Amount per Serving",ints[1]), ("Total Fat",(ints[3]/100)*ints[2]), ("Saturated Fat",(ints[4]/100)*(ints[3]/100)*ints[2]), ("Cholesterol",ints[5]), ("Fiber",ints[6]), ("Sugar",ints[7]), ("Protein",ints[8]), ("Sodium",ints[9]), ("USA",choices[ints[10]]), ("Caffeine",ints[11])]}
    return dictInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order, just print `dict(YourOrderedDict)`, if you care about the order you can :

```
for key, value in yourOrderedDict.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Hoping it helps